Katalon - Import a class defined in Keywords folder
I want to import a class defined in Keywords -> packageName -> className in one of my test cases to create objects of that class and use it's class variables. Example:
Keywords/packageName/test.groovy
    class TopBar {

    def hello = "Hello"
}

And inside the test cases, I want to import that class and declare an object out of it.
Example:
Test Cases/Test Folder/Top Left Bar:
import CustomKeywords.Idk.What.To.Type.Here.TopBar

TopBar topbar = new TopBar()
println topbar.hello

And the output should be

Hello

I've searched online resources but I could not find anything related to this.
